# Как сделать jar с maven?

Tags: java, maven

Всем привет, подскажете как собрать `maven project` в `jar` при этом:

- чтобы использовать плагин `resource`(создание ресурс фолдера)
- компайлинг
- executable jar
- assembly(чтобы экспортировать зависимости)